# Nivo Slider working on static HTML site but not on WP based site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

I'm converting a static HTML site to Wordpress for a client and I'm having a problem getting the Nivo slider to work.

It works perfectly on the HTML version [as can be seen here](http://www.drivelinelandrover.co.uk/) but on the Wordpress version [seen here](http://www.robotwp.com/fullphat/driveline/) it doesn't seem to show any of the images.

The Wordpress version's script is registering as it's applying some styles to the .slider element but the slideshow images are always set to display:none.

Anybody have any ideas?

EDIT;

The HTML version uses this;

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('.slider').nivoSlider({
    effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    slices:40,
    directionNav:false, //Next and Prev
    controlNav:false //1,2,3...

});
```

and the WP version uses this;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.slider').nivoSlider({
        effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices:40,
        directionNav:false, //Next and Prev
        controlNav:false //1,2,3...

    });

});
```

Comment: ah, I think I know why. On WP sites, use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: @martincarlin87 I already use `jQuery` instead of `$` and it still doesn't work...

Comment: you have two errors in javascript see the console panel of browser and remove them first

Comment: Yeah, you still use $ when using $('#frmContact').submit(function() - so fixing errors should be your first step.

Comment: @DeanElliott - when I checked the source I definitely saw numerous instances of `$`, just checked and it appears they are still there, starting at line 128 of the page source.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jquery.min.js file from the static version. Make sure to add the line below

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Adding the above line only seems to solve the problem if it is inserted in your footer AFTER the line below:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.terrafirma4x4.com/tfplugin/tfplugin-latest-jquery.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
```